# Room database Entity initialization

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-sqlite, android-room

we have following Json and model class. how to initiate Room entity database on this Json.

```
   {
    "ResultResponse": "Success",
    "OTPValue": "3239",
    "EmployeeInfo": [
        {
            "EmployeeCode": "EMP001",
            "Name": "Natheem",
            "ContactNo": "9952265503",
            "AlternativeContactNo": "9952265502",
            "Age": "22",
            "DOB": "1995-10-08T00:00:00",
            "ImagePath": "C:\\FaceTag\\FaceTag\\Images\\EMP001\\natheem.jpg",
            "Latitude": "1.104492000000000e+001",
            "Longitude": "7.701183000000000e+001",
            "Address1": "45, Bharathiyar Nagar",
            "Address2": "Coimbatore",
            "City": "Coimbatore",
            "State": "Tamilnadu",
            "Country": "India",
            "Zip": "641001",
            "IsSupervisor": false,
            "FormId": 0
        }
    ],
    "AdditionalField": null,
    "FieldControl": null
}
```

and my entity class is.

```
  @Entity(tableName = "tbl_device_register")
public class DeviceRegister {


    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("ResultResponse")
    @Expose
    private String resultResponse;
    @SerializedName("OTPValue")
    @Expose
    private String oTPValue;
    @SerializedName("EmployeeInfo")
    @Expose
    private List<EmployeeInfo> employeeInfo = null;
    @SerializedName("AdditionalField")
    @Expose
    private Object additionalField;
    @SerializedName("FieldControl")
    @Expose
    private Object fieldControl;
```

How to assign the Foreign key, and what about table relationship. most of the tutorials speaking about the basics. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Adding foreignKeys means we create connection between this entity and
>   some other class. In this parameter we declare parentColumns, which is
>   name of the id column from User class and childColumns, which is the
>   name of the user id column in Repo class.

The **ForeignKey** Structure is

```
@Entity(foreignKeys =
    [
        ForeignKey(
                entity = SOURCECLASSNAME::class,
                parentColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                childColumns = arrayOf("id"),
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE
        )
    ], indices = [Index(value = "id")]
)
```

Make sure, import below

```
import static android.arch.persistence.room.ForeignKey.CASCADE;
```

You can read [**`One-to-many relation`**](https://android.jlelse.eu/android-architecture-components-room-relationships-bf473510c14a).